# Horizonatl Gesture Swiping not working in My Flutter app

Tags: flutter

```
PageView(
            controller: _pageController,
            allowImplicitScrolling: true,
            children: [
              ...widget.storeImages
                  .map((image) => GestureDetector(
                        onHorizontalDragEnd: (drag) {
                          debugPrint('Drag.......');
                        },
                        child: Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.transparent,
                            image: DecorationImage(
                              fit: BoxFit.fill,
                              image: CachedNetworkImageProvider(image.assetId),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ))
                  .toList(),
            ],
          ),
```

i have a particular number of images in a container i need to move it from left to right and right to left using swipe gestures.

In that container i have 2 arrows back and forward, which it works perfectly because when i try to click it moves forward and backward

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping the children of the `PageView` with `GestureDetector` is causing the `PageView` to not detect the swiping gesture. If you want to execute some code when the user swipes, wrap your `PageView` instead:

```dart
GestureDetector(
  onHorizontalDragEnd: (drag) {
    debugPrint('Drag.......');
  },
  child: PageView(
    // ...
  ),
)
```

If you need to know the index of the current page being shown, get it from `_pageController.page`.